# Removing the remembered login and password list in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, security, authentication, ssms

I've recently used our company's spare laptop (that has a general user set up) while mine was being repaired. I've checked the "Remember password" option in SQL Server Management Studio when logging in to the database.

I need to clear the login and password information that I have used to prevent the next person that will use the laptop from using my login names and passwords. How can I do this?

Answer (score 368):

Another answer here also mentions since 2012 you can remove Remove cached login  via [How to remove cached server names from the Connect to Server dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993861/how-to-remove-cached-server-names-from-the-connect-to-server-dialog). Just confirmed this delete in MRU list works fine in 2016 and 2017.

SQL Server Management Studio **2017** delete the file
`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\14.0\SqlStudio.bin`

SQL Server Management Studio **2016** delete the file
`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\13.0\SqlStudio.bin`

SQL Server Management Studio **2014** delete the file
`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\12.0\SqlStudio.bin`

SQL Server Management Studio **2012** delete the file
`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\SqlStudio.bin`

SQL Server Management Studio **2008** delete the file  `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\SqlStudio.bin`

SQL Server Management Studio **2005** delete the file – same as above answer but the Vista path.
`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell\mru.dat`

These are profile paths for Vista / 7 / 8.

EDIT:

Note, `AppData` is a hidden folder. You need to show hidden folders in explorer.

EDIT:
You can simply press delete from the Server / User name drop down (confirmed to be working for SSMS v18.0). Original source from https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/17/sql-server-remove-cached-login-from-ssms-connect-dialog-sql-in-sixty-seconds-049/ which mentioned that this feature is available since 2012!

Comment: "%AppData%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\SqlStudio.bin"

Comment: The  mru file may exist in Vista/Win7, but for XP, I never found the mru file. I instead followed the above comment (renamed but did not delete) and Sql Manager happily recreated the SqlStudio.bin file next time I launched it, so the above comment is correct for XP users.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Removing `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\SqlStudio.bin` worked for me in Win7.

Comment: +1 My 'remember password' was not working correctly for some reason. Deleting this file allowed me to create the login again and it worked just fine. C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\ for Windows XP.

Comment: May be this can be an another question, but I am afraid that it' likely going to close as it could be very product specific. But is there any why to edit the information which is stored in above files? I'd like to remove some saved logins.

Comment: **%AppData%\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\SqlStudio.bin** for SSMS 2012 worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me with SQL 2008 R2. Just be sure you have SQL Studio closed before you do this or it recreates the file almost immediately.

Comment: Make sure you close SQL Server Management Studio before deleting, or the file will be recreated with credentials EDIT: Like @KyleHeon said

Comment: While I can't say it only impacts the login window, I can say this doesn't impact all settings across SSMS. I utilize the registered servers feature and after deleting this file those were still saved.

Comment: This worked great in V18: "EDIT: You can simply press delete from the Server / User name drop down (confirmed to be working for SSMS v18.0). Original source from https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/17/sql-server-remove-cached-login-from-ssms-connect-dialog-sql-in-sixty-seconds-049/ which mentioned that this feature is available since 2012!"

Comment: *"You can simply press delete from the Server / User name drop down"* I've just verified that that does **not** work in SSMS v17 and **does** work in SSMS v18. Pinal Dave's article says it works for the *Server Name* field, not the *User Name* field. As of v18, though, it definitely does work in the user name field.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm using SSMS 18.10 with a saved registration with 2 saved logins (`Me`: with password, `NotMe` without a saved password). I want to remove the `NotMe` login/userid). Selecting `NotMe` and pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> does **not** correctly remove the `NotMe` option, while it does seem to remove it from the list initially, it's still in the drop-down list, and immediately after removing it the Save button is disabled - argh.

Comment: @gluecks answer worked for me in 2023

Comment: FYI, I was able to adapt the information from the comment @T.J.Crowder left to remove credentials for a specific server in SSMS 2012.  Just hover over the target server in the drop-down menu, press the delete key, and then *restart SSMS*.  The next time you open it, you will be able to re-add the server without the old cached credentials.  If you do not restart SSMS, the old credentials will still be there.  I can also confirm that the delete key *does not* work to delete credentials directly in 2012.

Answer (score 138):

This works for SQL Server Management Studio v18.0

The file "SqlStudio.bin" doesn't seem to exist any longer. Instead my settings are all stored in this file:

`C:\Users\*********\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0\UserSettings.xml`

- Open it in any Texteditor like Notepad++
- ctrl+f for the username to be removed
- then delete the entire `<Element>.......</Element>` block
  that surrounds it.

**EDIT:**
An even easier and working solution for v18.0 (Preview 7) would be:

- Go to the "Connect to Server" dialogue window:

  [image]
- Click the down-arrow icon marked green in the screenshot.
- Use the arrow-keys on the keyboard to navigate up/down
- Press the DEL key on keyboard to delete the entry.
- Close the dialogue window and when you reopen it the entry will indeed be removed.

Comment: Confirmed this procedure works as recently as v18.9.1.

Comment: You need to close MS SQL Management Studio before edit UserSettings.xml, because It restore deleted login on closing.

Comment: Confirming this works in v18.12.1

Comment: Deleting items from the Connect to Server dialog did not work for me on v18.12. Editing the xml file did the job.

Comment: My plus is for the inclusion of the way to do it using the GUI.  Maybe a not really easily discoverable method, but having whacked things by making manual xml changes - use the GUI when you can.

Comment: Direct Path for SSMS v18.x:
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0\UserSettings.xml

Comment: The DEL method worked a charm on v19.0 Preview 3. Thank you. 

Comment: Deleting from dialog box works but you really have to follow the steps. Move between logins using arrow-keys on the keyboard and click on "delete" button on the keyboard. Any other attempts of using mouse, using backspace etc. just fail. Thanks this worked well in 2024.

Answer (score 45):

For those looking for the SSMS 2012 solution... see this answer:

[Remove cached login 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993861/how-to-remove-cached-login-from-the-connect-to-server-dialog-in-sql-server-2012)

Essentially, in 2012 you can delete the server from the server list dropdown which clears all cached logins for that server.

Works also in v17 (build 14.x).

Comment: 2014 users should use this!  I am using SSMS 2014, I didn't have SqlStudio.bin (see top answer), but I followed the link in this answer and it worked (and is much easier).

Comment: Note that despite the title of the link in this answer, "Remove cached login 2012", the answer it links to is about how to delete a cached _server name_, not a login.  I didn't read that linked answer carefully enough and was trying the technique to remove a single login from the Login dropdown list.  That doesn't work.  It only works when you're removing a server name from the Server Name dropdown list.  Along with deleting the server name it will also delete all cached logins for that server name; you can't delete just a single login and leave the others for that server.

Comment: I am using SSMS v18.4, and this solution worked for me. open Connect to Server > open Server name dropdown list and delete all saved logins.

Answer (score 33):

In my scenario I only wanted to remove a specific username/password from the list which had many other saved connections I didn't want to forget. It turns out the `SqlStudio.bin` file others are discussing here is a .NET binary serialization of the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UserSettings.SqlStudio` class, which can be deserialized, modified and reserialized to modify specific settings.

To accomplish removal of the specific login, I created a new C# .Net 4.6.1 console application and added a reference to the namespace which is located in the following dll: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UserSettings.dll` (your path may differ slightly depending on SSMS version)

From there I could easily create and modify the settings as desired:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UserSettings;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var settingsFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\13.0\SqlStudio.bin");

        // Backup our original file just in case...
        File.Copy(settingsFile.FullName, settingsFile.FullName + ".backup");

        BinaryFormatter fmt = new BinaryFormatter();

        SqlStudio settings = null;

        using(var fs = settingsFile.Open(FileMode.Open))
        {
            settings = (SqlStudio)fmt.Deserialize(fs);
        }

        // The structure of server types / servers / connections requires us to loop
        // through multiple nested collections to find the connection to be removed.
        // We start here with the server types

        var serverTypes = settings.SSMS.ConnectionOptions.ServerTypes;

        foreach (var serverType in serverTypes)
        {
            foreach (var server in serverType.Value.Servers)
            {
                // Will store the connection for the provided server which should be removed
                ServerConnectionSettings removeConn = null;

                foreach (var conn in server.Connections)
                {
                    if (conn.UserName == "adminUserThatShouldBeRemoved")
                    {
                        removeConn = conn;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (removeConn != null)
                {
                    server.Connections.RemoveItem(removeConn);
                }
            }
        }

        using (var fs = settingsFile.Open(FileMode.Create))
        {
            fmt.Serialize(fs, settings);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, worked like a charm
How did you figure out 

1) That that file is a .NET binary serialization of the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UserSettings.SqlStudio class and

2) The reference to the namespace is located in the  dll Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UserSettings.dll and how you found its location

Comment: @DrManhattan If you binary serialize a very simple .NET class to file and open it in a text editor you will see a mix of binary data and text. Some of the text will be the values of your strings (if you have any in the class which was serialized). However the start of the file will be metadata about the root type which was serialized and the assembly it came from. Open your `SqlStudio.bin` file and you will see both `..UserSettings` and `..UserSettings.SqlStudio`. From there it was easy to find `..UserSettings.dll` in the same directory as `ssms.exe`, which contained the namespace and class.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks. I saw the metadata `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UserSettings, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral...`, you have taught me how to fish, thanks

Comment: I ran this code with the SSMS running and then checked there to see if it worked by restarting SSMS, and it didn't work, because the SqlStudio.bin was already loaded in memory by SSMS and then re-written by it before closing. Then I ran the code with SSMS closed and worked like a charm.

Comment: Worked here too, so +1, but on my computer I didn't have the required DLL in the SQL Server directory. When I browsed I finally found it under the VS2017 directory where I would have expected it in the first place, except it wasn't in the Assemblies list in the Add Reference window. Oh well.

Comment: very nice solution. for me I'm using SQLServer 17. so I changed some paths.
- for Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UserSettings.dll i used this path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\"
- for SqlStudio.bin i used this path ""C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\14.0\"

Answer (score 22):

There is a really simple way to do this using a more recent version of SQL Server Management Studio (I'm using 18.4)

1. Open the "Connect to Server" dialog
2. Click the "Server Name" dropdown so it opens
3. Press the down arrow on your keyboard to highlight a server name
4. Press delete on your keyboard

Login gone! No messing around with dlls or bin files.

Answer (score 12):

Delete entire node "Element" (inside "Connections" tree) from XML file, used by version 18 or higher.

C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0\UserSettings.xml

[image]

Answer (score 9):

As gluecks pointed out, no more `SqlStudio.bin` in **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18**. I also found this `UserSettings.xml` in `%AppData%\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0`. But removing the `<Element>` containing the credential seems not working, it comes right back on the xml file, if I close and re-open it again.

Turns out, you need to **close the SQL Server Management Studio first**, then edit the `UserSettings.xml` file in your favorite editor, e.g. Visual Studio Code. I guess it's cached somewhere in SSMS besides this xml file?! And it's not on `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager\Windows Credentials`.

Answer (score 5):

For SQL Server Management Studio 2008

1. You need to go **C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Application
   Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell**
2. Delete **SqlStudio.bin**

Answer (score 4):

Delete:

C:\Documents and Settings\%Your Username%\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell\mru.dat"

Comment: I have installed MSSSMS2008E under Windows 7 and even have not mru.data neither in %AppData%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell not in %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell. But Robin Luiten's answer helps under both Windows XP and Windows 7. As far as I see our controversy takes place often: http://tinyurl.com/ybc8x8p

Answer (score 3):

In XP, the .mru.dat file is in C:\Documents and Settings\Name\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\ShellSEM

However, removing it won't do anything.

To remove the list in XP, cut the sqlstudio bin file from C:\Documents and Settings\Name\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell and paste it on your desktop.

Try SQL

If it has worked, then delete the sqlstudio bin file from desktop.

Easy  :)

Answer (score 1):

Select the Login drop down arrow. Delete the users from the list

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 18.12.1, it is a little different.

Navigate to `C:\Users\%userName%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0`

If you want to start from scratch you could try delete the `UserSettings.xml` file.

In my case I just wanted to remove one item from the dropdown list.

This involves editing the xml file.

1. BACKUP UserSettings.xml
2. Search for the name of the server you want to remove from the dropdown list
3. Go up the file to the `<Element>`
4. Comment out the  block including the closing `</Element>`
5. Close and reopen SQL Server Management Studio
6. You'll see that server is no longer in the list

At this point will probably see your text editor say that SQL updated the file.  This is only timestamps, so nothing to be to worried about.

If you are happy with your changes you can delete the commented out block and save the file.