# Deleting a SQL Server from the list in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a SQL Server instance that I'd like to remove from the list that shows up in the available servers in Object Explorer. How do I do this?

Comment: Here is the same [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10996066/6598234) that you looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you mean the dropdown list of servers when making a new connection, you simply highlight the row in the dropdown and hit <kbd>delete</kbd>.