# 2 instances of SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server

Due to some weird issues, I have re-installed SQL Server 2014 Express. Upon logging in with SSMS, I saw there are now 2 instances named `SQLEXPRESS` (shown below).

[image]

1. Why are there 2 instances named `SQLEXPRESS`? Does it have something to do with the re-installation?
2. Can / should I remove one of them? Please suggest the ways to do so.

Comment: I think both are same since you can't install two instances with same name on same box

Comment: I see. In this case, could / should I remove one of them from the list? How could that be done?

Comment: try this out:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349668/removing-the-remembered-login-and-password-list-in-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: above link has some references on how to clear ssms cache