# SSMS Remove Login from Connect to Server dialog

Tags: authentication, ssms

I would really like to remove a user name from the SSMS "Connect to Server" dialog, but I can't figure out how, and I can't find if anywhere.

I don't want to delete the SqlStudio.bin file, or the mru.dat file, because that resets *all* the login information, plus  a bunch of other settings as well.

Also, I already tried hovering over the user name and hitting the delete key. I even tried the backspace key for good measure. No luck on those.

If anyone knows of something I haven't tried, I'd be most grateful.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. - SSMS 2016 on Windows 10

Comment: To do this without deleting the entire server as the answer suggests, you can [modify the SqlStudio.bin file via c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349668/removing-the-remembered-login-and-password-list-in-sql-server-management-studio/52227566#52227566)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To remove a saved login, delete the associated saved server name. Expand the server name drop-down list, hover over a server name, and hit the delete key.

Comment: Brilliant. To remove a login entry, it’s much easier to delete and re-enter the corresponding server name altogether than to hassle with the bin file or registry or third-party tools. Maybe in a few major releases, they add the [Del] feature to the logins as well.

Comment: They added it to the logins as well.  :-)